# Use database google cloud mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new mysql and Google cloud SQL. I created a database and now can't seem to use it. Please see the list of commands below which leads to the error

```
Google SQL Client

Type "help" or "?" for help.

Connecting to Google SQL database "evident-castle-346:pocsql01" on host None.
Using readline for history management.
Loading history file "/Users/*********/.googlesql/evident-castle-346#pocsql01.hist"
sql> show database
Database: evident-castle-346:pocsql01
Vendor:   MySQL AB
Product:  MySQL
Version:  5.5.34

sql> use evident-castle-346:pocsql01;
ERROR:google_sql:(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-castle 346:pocsql01' at line 1")
sql>
```

I can't seem to figure out what the error in my syntax is.

Please help

Comment: Try wrapping backticks ``` around the database name

Comment: Tried that still does not work.

Comment: Figured it out.
    python google_sql.py evident-castle-346:pocsql01 sample

where 

evident-castle-346:pocsql01 is the instance id 
sample is the database name